# How to find line number of searched string in Tkinter Textbox and then insert string just before

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, line

let's say i have a tkinter Textbox like this :

textbox =

```
Hello world !
Life is good on earth
Winter is already there
```

How do i search for `"good"`, get the line number and insert something on the line number just before ?

Expected result :

```
Hello world !
New sentence inserted here
Life is good on earth
Winter is already there
```

I know how to use the `.find("good")` method to get the number of characters before "good" is reached but since i want to be able to use the `textbox.insert()` i need the line number (not the number of characters) like `1.0` to specify where i want to insert the new sentence in the textbox .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may play with the tkinter index:

```
from tkinter import *
 
root = Tk()
fram = Frame(root)
Label(fram,text='Text to find:').pack(side=LEFT)
edit = Entry(fram)
edit.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
edit.focus_set()
butt = Button(fram, text='Find') 
butt.pack(side=RIGHT)
fram.pack(side=TOP)
text = Text(root)
text.insert('1.0','''Hello world !
Life is good on earth
Winter is already there''')
text.pack(side=BOTTOM)
 
def find():
    s = edit.get()
    if s:
        idx = '1.0'
        idx = text.search(s, idx, nocase=1, stopindex=END)
        if idx:
            text.insert(idx.split('.')[0]+'.0', 'New sentence inserted here\n')
    edit.focus_set()
butt.config(command=find) 
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify an index with `linestart` to get the start of the line.

For example, assuming that the variable `index` contains the character position of a match, such as 2.8, you can get the start of the line like this:

```
f"{index} linestart"  # eg: "2.8 linestart"
```

In your code it might look something like this:

```
index = text.search("good", "1.0", "end")
text.insert(f"{index} linestart", "New sentence inserted here\n")
```